# IntelliJ XML navigation shortcut

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, shortcut

Is there an IntelliJ shortcut that allows you to jump outward, from a tag to its parent, or to its previous or next sibling tag?  I don't see a configurable action in the Keymap dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcuts are the same as for method navigation (the actions are called "Next Method" and "Previos Method" and are in the Navigate menu):

Alt + Up  - navigates you to the parent of the current tag

Alt + Down - navigates you to the next sibling tag